# Orig_iat missing from payload when implementing customing JSONWebTokenSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am implementing a custom JSONWebTokenSerializer. It's working fine so far but I need to enable token refresh but I when I do and try to refresh the token, I get the validation error `orig_iat field is required`. On inspecting the payload returned from `jwt_payload_handler`, there isn't any `orig_iat field` attribute.

```
class CustomJWTSerializer(JSONWebTokenSerializer):

@property
def username_field(self):
    return "username_or_email_or_phone"

def validate(self, attrs):
    username = attrs.get('username_or_email_or_phone', None)
    credentials = {
        'username': username,
        'password': attrs.get('password')
    }

    if all(credentials.values()):
        user = authenticate(**credentials)

        if user:
            if not user.is_active:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    'This user has been deactivated.'
                )

            payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)

            return {
                'token': jwt_encode_handler(payload),
                'user': user
            }

        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'A user with this credentials was not found.'
            )

    else:
        msg = _('Please provide an (username or email or phone number) and password.')
        raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
```

Here is are my `JWT_AUTH` setting:

```
JWT_AUTH = {
'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=1),
'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'common.utilities.auth.jwt_response_payload_handler',
'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',
'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',
'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': False,

}
```

Comment: I was also facing the same error. One way is to make a custom jwt_payload_handler. Add all the fields you want in your token and add 'orig_iat' field as well. Give the path of this custom function in 'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER'. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

> If JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH is True, non-expired tokens can be "refreshed" to obtain a brand new token with renewed expiration time.[[JWTDoc](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/)]

Sorry, found my bug. Changed `'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': False` to `'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,`.. It now works